# TSQL request is required

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The task sounds like this:
Choose the top 10 cities for the next store opening

Columns: City | A priority

Priority is defined as the number of buyers in the city
There should be no shop in the city.

Preliminary wrong decision:

```
SELECT
    City,
    COUNT(1) as [Priority]
FROM
    Sales.vIndividualCustomer
GROUP BY City
EXCEPT
SELECT
    City,
    COUNT(1) as [Priority]
FROM
    Purchasing.vVendorWithAddresses 
GROUP BY City
ORDER BY [Priority] DESC
GO
```

Result:
Uniqueness disappears as soon as I start counting priority. Maybe there is another way?

PS: Used as a database AdventureWorks2016 from Microsoft.

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: provide sample data and desired output

Comment: Have already given the correct answer. I will attach some sample data next time, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `NOT EXISTS` subquery

```sql
SELECT
    ic.City,
    COUNT(1) as [Priority]
FROM
    Sales.vIndividualCustomer ic
GROUP BY
    ic.City
HAVING NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM
        Purchasing.vVendorWithAddresses va
    WHERE
        va.City = ic.City)
ORDER BY [Priority] DESC;
```

> Note that if you wish to refer to aggregated columns then the `NOT EXISTS` will have to be in a `WHERE` not a `HAVING`